# How to remove all require and define statements form my javascript library using r.js optimizer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd, r.js

I'm trying to do something like what jQuery team is doing on Github. They brake their library into sub modules(https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src) but at the end they concatenate them all together and remove all require/define statements so that you don't need to include requireJS in your project. When I try to optimize my files using r.js I still get require/define statements in my final code. How can I concatenate all these modules without need to user requireJS to load my library?

The question you marked as duplicate is looking for jQuery specific solution how ever it's really complicated I'm just putting jQuery example to show what I want to do, I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at their [build.js grunt task](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/build/tasks/build.js). Specifically look at the convert function inside the grunt task which is responsible for stripping out all the `define([…],` calls and replacing them with `var moduleName =`.

Comment: Thanks but It's a little bit complicated to use jQuery solution I'm looking for an automatic tool that does this, how ever I found https://www.npmjs.org/package/amdclean that does the job.

Comment: @ImanMohamadi that's a nice find. I will definitely be taking a look into amdclean. My only issue with these additional build steps on top of r.js or browserify is that it tends to ruin any source maps that might have been generated earlier in the build process. Personally I'd prefer having source maps over saving a kilobyte or two, I just wish I could have both.